SVN Merge including revisions from two different branches simulteanously
I'm using SVN for my versionning, and using the following fixed branch architecture :
/my-project
     |-- production
     |-- staging
     |-- develop

Every commit pushed on the develop branch is merged to the staging branch then to the production branch
However, using TortoiseSVN, when browsing on my production branch including the merged revisions, I noticed that one of commit included merged commitfrom both the staging and develop branches at the same time. (the following image showing the issue)

When asking the developper that performed the merge, he told me that he only merged the commit from the staging branch (205 on the image) on the production branch. The changed code confirm that only the 205's code has been merged on the production branche. The code comming from the other commits - the ones from the develop branch - hasn't been included in the revision.
I don't know if it can matter, but the 200, 201, 202 and 203 patch has been merged on the staging branch independantly before merging the 205 on the production branch (the numbers have been anonymized)
Such behaviour should not be possible, or is there something I could be missing ? I don't know how a merge could include commits from multiple branches and yet SVN seems to understand it this way. Specially as the developper mentions that the included merges from develop weren't included when he performed the merge.
Could that be a bug from SVN ? I'm using SVN 1.9, which isn't new but I never encountered such behaviour before
Thanks for your time :)
